# Django Filter not working with user choosen place

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-filter

in the code the product is assigned with place, so the products  should be come with user choosen place. But now i am getting all the products name with user choosen place also those products are not assigned with any country.

```
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == ("places","coffee"):
        kwargs["queryset"] = models.Region.objects.filter(
            country=request._user_places,
        )

    return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: edit the question with your ```models.py``` added

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

```
def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name in ("places","coffee"):
        kwargs["queryset"] = models.Region.objects.filter(
            country__in=request._user_places,
        )

    return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: ,sorry it did not worked

Comment: `.name` should be `in` not `==`
and does `_user_places` return a list or what?